# XPath for select name and filter by child atribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML like this:

```
<xml>
  <...>
    <...>
      <test name="Test A">
          ...
        <status status="PASS">
      </test>

      <test name="Test B">
          ...
        <status status="FAIL">
      </test>

      <test name="Test C">
          ...
        <status status="PASS">
      </test>
</xml>
```

I want in one XPath select names of passed tests: `"Test A", "TestC"`
Now I have to XPath and do not know how to put them together.

`xpath_tests_name = "//tests/@name'`
`xpath_passed_tests = "//test[status[@status='PASS']]"`

I know I can do it in same loop: first get passed test and for each passed get its name.

However, I am looking for "the most beautiful" solution.

Comment: Simply append "/@name" to the end of your 2nd xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am looking for "the most beautiful" solution.

A more direct (and more beautiful, in my personal opinion) way of writing this expression would be

```
/xml/test[status/@status = 'PASS']/@name
```

The expression returns a set of *attribute nodes*. To extract their values, you might have to process them further, depending on your XPath environment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you correcly, but if you want a specific one do it like this:

```
//status[@status="PASS"]/parent::test[@name="Test A"]
```

And all the names that are PASS:

```
//status[@status="PASS"]/parent::test/@name
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think that you meant to write `//status[@status="PASS"]/parent::test/@name` instead of `//status[@status="PASS"]/parent::test[@name]`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller didn't know that it's possible to do that, thanks.